# how to stop scheduled auto reboots on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, scheduled-task

i installed a encrypted script on my server. all works as expected but there is a scheduled reboot after installing that script.

server auto reboots at a specific time everyday.
how can i stop this ? i can't read the scripty since it is encrypted

server info -  Ubuntu 20.04 (LTS) x64

Comment: Check `cron` record for `root`

Comment: thank you. found it on "nano /etc/crontab"

Answer (score 1):

You can check in `cron` records for `root` user. IMHO other users can't reboot your machine.

And next time be careful when install unknown scripts :)